# Calling a method on Session Timeout?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website with multiple pages. Each page has a "Save as Draft" method that will save the users progress. I have a session timeout of 40 minutes, and I was wondering how I would make it so that whenever the session is expired, the page automatically calls "Save as Draft" (so it's not lost)

How would I start on doing something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't: the session expires server side and cannot send a message to the browser (it doesn't even know whether the user still sees the page or has closed the browser).

You *could* set a client-side timeout to save the page (as draft) to the server, but this has the effect of refreshing the session! So maybe just do an automatic "save as draft" every 5 - 10 minutes, thereby keeping your session (plus a draft copy of the work done).

Answer (score 1):

In .Net, you can do it via Global.asax in Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) routine. I use this to do some resource release work.

Answer (score 1):

you can call function in global.asax when session expire's like this

```
Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Session.Item("sessionid") Is Nothing Then
        If Session.Item("sessionid").ToString = "1" Then
            ClsUtilities.CustomerLogout()
        ElseIf Session.Item("sessionid").ToString = "2" Then
            ClsUtilities.Logout()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```