# asp.net 4 form authentication: perform action on user session expiration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, form-authentication

I'm using "Forms" authentication in asp.net 4, with a fixed time before make the session expire.

I need to call a method that use some variables in Session just before logging out, but I am not able to handle the case when the user's session is expired (it just redirect me to the login page). For example, I would like to log something like "User  session is expired!". Moreover, I need some info stored in Session.

I tried to use the Session_end method, but it seems that session expiration "event" does not trigger this function.

The configuration in web.config is:

```
<sessionState
    mode="InProc"
    cookieless="false"
    timeout="70"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
          loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
          slidingExpiration="true"
          timeout="1" />
    </authentication>
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="false" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

The 1-second delay for expiration is for debug purpose.

Is it possible to do what I need to?

Many thanks

Comment: Just realized that the session lasts 70 minutes, while authentication just 1. Found this: http://completedevelopment.blogspot.it/2009/12/caution-with-using-sessiontimeout-and.html but when the authentication expires, the authenticationCookie is Nothing, therefore I can't use the code in this blog.

Answer (score 0):

Think this may have already been answered.

[Calling a method on Session Timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161379/calling-a-method-on-session-timeout)

Apologies if this is different.

Comment: post this in the comment section, not over here